# ERROR 1100 (HY000) at line 11084: Table 'search_index' was not locked with LOCK TABLES

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, restore

I'm trying to import a `mysqldump` backup of a `drupal` database taken from a server running `MySQL 5.0` (which will be upgraded to `5.5`) onto my local machine running `MySQL 5.5.23`. The import fails with the below error:

```
ERROR 1100 (HY000) at line 11084: Table 'search_index' was not locked with LOCK TABLES
```

When I open up the backup at line `11084` here is what I get:

```
LOCK TABLES `sessions` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `sessions` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `sessions` VALUES ...
-- MySQL dump 10.11
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: drupal
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version       5.0.77-log

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Table structure for table `search_index`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `search_index`;        <=== LINE 11084
SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client;
SET character_set_client = utf8;
CREATE TABLE `search_index` (
  `word` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  `sid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `type` varchar(16) default NULL,
  `score` float default NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `word_sid_type` (`word`,`sid`,`type`),
  KEY `sid_type` (`sid`,`type`),
  KEY `word` (`word`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client;
```

I checked the other statements and normally `INSERT` statements are followed by `UNLOCK TABLES;`. Accordingly if **I make the below modifications to the `mysqldump` file the problem is fixed**:

```
INSERT INTO `sessions` VALUES ...
UNLOCK TABLES;                   <=== ADDED LINE
-- MySQL dump 10.11
[...]
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `search_index`;
```

I don't know what's wrong there but the whole comment block starting with `-- MySQL dump 10.11` is the same as the one at the beginning of the `mysqldump` file, and it looks like `mysqldump` started a new dump while writing the `INSERT INTO sessions` statements which were not closed properly with `UNLOCK TABLES;`.

**Does someone have any idea as to what's going on here?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My initial guess would be that when the mysqldump file was being created, the option [**single-transaction**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_single-transaction) was not used.

According to MySQL Documentation on [**single-transaction**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_single-transaction)

> The --single-transaction option and the --lock-tables option are mutually exclusive because LOCK TABLES causes any pending transactions to be committed implicitly.

The fact that you embedded `UNLOCK TABLES;` into the dump manually shows that neither option was called when the mysqldump was first created. Thus, upon reload, this error reared its ugly head.

Comment: Using `--single-transaction` did fix the issue :) Thanks for much. What's weird is that we never had this issue before, it only started occurring yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this error comes when you have the following command in your sql dump without any insert

```
LOCK TABLES `table_name` WRITE;
```

Just remove the above line and it will resolve the issue for you.

Hope it helps

Cheers
S